# ffmpeg how to save decoded audio data to pcm

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg

I have succeed decode audio data from a mp4 using avcodec_decode_audio4， I want to save the decoded frames,so I tried below

```js
if (got_frame) {
  int size;
  uint8_t *data;
  int ref = 0;
  ret = swr_convert(swr, &data, frame->nb_samples, (const uint8_t **)frame->extended_data, frame->nb_samples);
  //fwrite(data, 1, frame->nb_samples, fp_audio);
  ref++;
  int szie = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, 2, 1024, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP, 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < frame->linesize[0]/4; i++)
  {
    fwrite(frame->data[0] + 4*i, 1, 4, fp_audio);
    fwrite(frame->data[1] + 4*i, 1, 4, fp_audio);
    ref++;
  }



  av_frame_unref(frame);
}
```

but the pcm sounds strange, I also tried directed write as follows

```js
fwrite(frame->data[0], 1, frame->linesize[0], fp_audio);
```

or:

```js
fwrite(frame->data[0], 1, frame->linesize[0], fp_audio);
fwrite(frame->data[1], 1, frame->linesize[0], fp_audio);
```

I know that the decoded pcm is AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FLTP is planar float, so in case of stereo, you have two buffers, data[0] and data[1], which are per-channel planes.

For things like .wav or so, you typically want to write interleaved data, so basically an array where each even entry is left and each odd entry is right channel. To do that, convert to FLT (without P). Also note that .wav typically uses int16, not float, so for that, convert to S16.

Decoders output planar because that's how compressed streams typically layout their data, so for the individual decoders, this makes more sense.

Comment: I use some tools like cool edit to play pcm ,I know convert to s16 can play .but I just want to write the decoded data in some form not translated to s16 , that can play

Comment: appreciated your answer， convert to FLT (without P).  how should I do it  in this code segmant

Comment: swr example: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/resampling_audio.c

Comment: thank you，i know how to use swr to trans it , I donn't know how  by by my self（not use FFMPEG‘s API ）

Comment: Oh, I see. OK. So assume you have a planar buffer like AVFrame, do "float *left = frame->extended_data[0], *right = frame->extended_data[1];", allocate a buffer (float *dst) of sizeof(float) * 2 * frame->nb_samples, and then interleave into it: for (int i = 0; i < frame->nb_samples; i++) { dst[2 * i + 0] = left[i]; dst[2 * i + 1] = right[i]; }. Note that this will be a lot slower than what libswresample does, since it's straight C, whereas libswresample uses x86 (SIMD) assembly.